# Jquery Carousel won't reset to beginning and layout issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I can't seem to get the last slide to go back to the first slide.  I also have a problem when clicking on previous slide the next slide goes below the current slide for a second.  If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.  Unfortunately don't have the site uploaded so here's the code:

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.next-arrow').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    };

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

  });

  $('.prev-arrow').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if (prevSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').last();
      nextDot = $('.dot').last();
    };

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

  });




};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.s-bar {
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .s-dots {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .s-dots > li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline;
    }
    .active-dot {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .prev,
    .next {
      width: 20px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    .carousel-text {
      font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 1.8em;
      color: #ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      left: 30px;
      top: 30px;
    }
    .slide {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -500px;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 360px;
    }
    .active-slide {
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 360px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-main">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide active-slide">
      <div class="pic">
        <img src="pic1.png" width="1000" height="360">
        <div class="carousel-text">
          <h1>Welcome to the Shabby to Chic Workshop.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="pic">
        <img src="pic2.png" width="1000" height="360">
        <div class="carousel-text">
          <h1>We make custom furmiture.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="pic">
        <img src="pic3.png" width="1000" height="360">
        <div class="carousel-text">
          <h1>Come visit us today!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="s-bar">
      <a href="#" class="prev-arrow">
        <img src="la.png" width="20" height="40">
      </a>
      <ul class="s-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">
          <img src="dot.png" width="10" height="40">
        </li>
        <li class="dot">
          <img src="dot.png" width="10" height="40">
        </li>
        <li class="dot">
          <img src="dot.png" width="10" height="40">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="next-arrow">
        <img src="ra.png" width="20" height="40">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code for the `prev` click handler, after the `if` to:

```
nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
```

and

```
nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
```

Also, in CSS you have the `next` and `prev` classes, whereas in HTML, you have `next-arrow` and `prev-arrow`. They should be the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  I've changed the nextDot.addClass('active-dot');  and the CSS as suggested.  The nextSlide should be prevSlide though I think.  Anyway I tried both but still no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the carousel so it loops round now.  After using Firebug I realized the '.slide' classes needed to be contained in a another div, the '.active-slide' class was being added to the '.s-bar' and hence not showing the first slide.  For the layout problem I changed the '.active-slide' to display: absolute, instead of block.  Having two slides momentarily as both blocks was causing the problem.